# Переименование файлов определённого расширения

Tags: bat

Имеется папка, в ней лежит .bat файл и возможно один файл .img. Его название неизвестно. Как можно проверить существует ли он, и если существует, то переименовать его в определённое имя?

Comment: Просто `rename *.img new_name.*` не подойдет? Если файла нет, просто выведет, что скопировано 0 файлов.

Comment: insolor, нет. Нужно именно условие, т.к. в него нужно будет будет вставить ещё команду